# Basketball-who gets the point?

Tags: rules, basketball

If a person of the opposite team shoots and you try to block the ball but you touch it and the ball still goes in will it count as your score or the other teams score?

Answer (score 10):

If the ball travels through your opponent's basket, your opponent gets the points.

> **Rule 5, Section I, part D of the [2014-15 NBA Rule Book](https://turnernbahangtime.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/2014-15-nba-rule-book.pdf)**
>
> d. A field goal accidentally scored in an opponent’s basket shall be added to the opponent’s score, credited to the opposing player nearest the player whose actions caused the ball to enter the basket.

Comment: The rule is right, your comment above it is not.  If you purposely score on your opponents basket then no point is awarded even though the ball travels through the opponent's basket.

Comment: I don't see provision for that in the NBA rule book. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 3):

FIBA and NBA are essentially the same on the point of accidentally scoring in your own basket.

The FIBA Rules state:

> **16.2.2.** If a player accidentally scores a field goal in his team’s basket, the goal counts 2 points and shall be recorded as having been
>   scored by the captain of the opposing team on the playing court

In other words, if you deflect a ball during a shot, rebound or pass and the ball goes in your own basket, the field goal counts as 2 points for your opponents.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXtWVm4vRvk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8QhF5SKVFo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6SA4v719lM

Even forgetting which basket is your own, and scoring the wrong basket still counts 2 points for the opponents.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aj-omMYoTo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRTqml_hL_c

Answer (score 2):

If you accidentally get the ball in the wrong basket it counts however if it was done on purpose such as a field goal attempt it does not.

**NBA rule 5 section I part D** states:

A field goal accidentally scored in an opponent’s basket shall be added to the opponent’s score, credited to the opposing player nearest the player whose actions caused the ball to enter the basket.

.....However.....

**NBA rule 5 section I part E**:
It is a violation for a player to attempt a field goal at an opponent’s basket. The opposing team will be awarded the ball at the free throw line extended.

These are essentially the same in **FIBA** rules:

**16.2.2.** If a player accidentally scores a field goal in his team’s basket, the goal counts 2
points and shall be recorded as having been scored by the captain of the opposing
team on the playing court.
**16.2.3.** If a player deliberately scores a field goal in his team’s basket, it is a violation and
the goal does not count.